# How to Handle Additional Attributes in Many to Many Table in POJOs when Access Patterns Rely on One to Many?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, one-to-many

```
CREATE TABLE order (
    order_id INT
    ,...
    ,CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);
CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id INT
    ,item_list_price DECIMAL(10,2)
    ,...
    , CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
CREATE TABLE order_item (
    order_id INT
    ,item_id INT
    ,order_item_current_price DECIMAL(10,2);
    ,CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id)
    ,CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (order_id) ...
    ,CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (item_id) ...
);
```

An `Order` has Many `Item`s; Each `Item` may belong to Many `Order`s.

An `Item`'s price can change at any time. In order for a Customer to check how much he paid for an `Item` in the past, the `order_item_cost` field exists in the `order_item` table.

When the end user checks the `Item`s for sale, it would pull a List of Items with the item id, name, and listPrice, but not the currentPrice (as the currentPrice only relates to historical reporting in conjunction with an `order`, not purchasing a new `item`)
.

When the customer wishes to check his historical purchases and what he paid for each item at the time, it would pull an Order with a List of Items including the item id, name, and currentPrice, but not the listPrice (as the listPrice only relates to purchasing a new item, not historical reporting).

**So even though my relational schema has a Many to Many relationship between Order and Item, my POJOs think that there is a One to Many relationship between Order and Item, because there will never be an access pattern that requires the Many to Many**

Here are my current POJOs (stripped down to be concise):

```
public class Order {
    private int id;
    private String status;
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private List<Item> items;
    ...
}
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
    private double listPrice; // List price of item, capable of changing over time
    private double currentPrice; // represents the order_item_cost field in order_item table
    ...
}
```

As you can notice, I did not put a `List<Order>` in the `Item` class, because I can't imagine ever needing to know every possible `Order` ever used that purchased and `Item`.

This feels wrong, however. I'm wondering if I should take out the `currentPrice` member variable from `Item` and make a new POJO called `OrderItem` which reflects the `order_item` table:

```
public class OrderItem {
    private Order order;
    private Item item;
    private double cost;
}
public class Order {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order_item")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}
public class Item {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order_item")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}
```

But, again, the access patterns would never require an Item to find all orders associated with it. Should the Item class instead be something like:

```
public class Item {
    @OneToMany
    private Order order;
}
```

Or, is there a more appropriate way to use Hibernate to handle this?

In summary: My DB has a Many to Many schema, as one `item` can belong to many `order`s, and each `order` can have many `item`s, and I wish to record the price at which the customer bought the item at the time, because the list price of the `item` can change. The access patterns for my application however only require it to look like a One to Many relationship between `order` and `item`. I'm not sure how this is supposed to be handled with POJOs or hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to model the OrderItem object, because it is a relationship object with its own properties (cost). You should model Order 1->n OrderItem n->1 Item. The DB should be modeled similarly -- an order does not contain items, because the price isn't the item price, it's the order_item price.